stdev of delta hedged portfolio for call option !=0. Why?
I wrote a Monte-Carlo simulation of delta hedging for a european call. R and Sigma are fixed.
I start simulation with zero money and short call option. At each step I borrow money to buy 'delta' of assets.
At the end of simulation I look at my debt after option settlement. This is fee I should have been payed for the option.
My question: I've noticed that stddev( my cash after all settlements ) != 0. But, it is still << than stdev of payoff. That means that delta hedging did not hedge me completely. Is it ok? Why?
The following code gives me
required_initial_fee mean = 72.17 stdev = 0.56
discounted_option_payoff mean = 74.34 stdev = 426.68
from numpy import log, sqrt, exp, maximum
from math import erf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

@np.vectorize
def N_cdf(x):
    'Cumulative distribution function for the standard normal distribution'
    return (1.0 + erf(x / sqrt(2.0))) / 2.0

def BS_CALL_DELTA(S, K, T, r, sigma):
    d1 = ( log(S/K) + (r + 0.5 * sigma**2) * T ) / (sigma * sqrt(T))
    return N_cdf(d1)

S0 = 100 # Initial stock price
K = 100 # Strike price
r = 0.05 # Risk-free interest rate
sigma = 0.5 # Volatility
T = 3000 # Time to expiration
N = 100000 # Number of simulations
days_per_year = 250 # Time steps per year

#simulate price path
np.random.seed(2024)
dt = 1.0/days_per_year
# simulate path
simulated_paths = np.zeros((T, N))
simulated_paths[0] = S0
for i in range(0, T-1):
    w = np.random.standard_normal(N)
    simulated_paths[i+1] = simulated_paths[i] * (1 + r*dt + sigma * np.sqrt(dt)*w)

        
previous_delta = np.zeros(N)

# Total amount of borrowings is stored in 'debt' variable. Daily continuous interest rate is accrued on this debt
debt = np.zeros(N)

for t_i in range(0, T - 1):
    S_i = simulated_paths[t_i] 
    year_fraction_left_to_maturity = float(T - t_i) / days_per_year
    delta = BS_CALL_DELTA(S_i, K, year_fraction_left_to_maturity, r, sigma)
    
    # As Im doing delta hedging, by the end of the period I must own 'delta' amount of shares on the previous step I had 'previous_delta' amount. So I need to buy 'delta-previous_delta' of shares
    settled_cash_out = (delta - previous_delta) * S_i

    previous_delta = delta
    
    # I lend money to buy stocks. This is my total due
    debt = debt * exp(r / days_per_year) + settled_cash_out

# now I need to handle the last day:
S_final = simulated_paths[-1]
option_payoff = maximum.reduce([S_final - K, np.zeros(N)])
discounted_option_payoff = option_payoff * exp( -r * T / days_per_year)

# at the end of the last step I sell all my stocks (I have previous_delta of stocks) and pay payoff
settled_cash_out = -S_final * previous_delta + option_payoff

debt = debt * exp(r / days_per_year) + settled_cash_out

#how much money should I take as a commission to have 0 pnl by the end of the contract, to compensate my spendings on debt
required_initial_fee = debt * exp( -r * T / days_per_year)
print("required_initial_fee", round(required_initial_fee.mean(), 2), round(required_initial_fee.std(), 2))
print("discounted_option_payoff", round(discounted_option_payoff.mean(), 2), round(discounted_option_payoff.std(), 2))


Are you talking about a time-series standard deviation of your (borrowed) cash amounts from $t=0$ to the maturity of the option? I don't see why you would expect stdev to be zero in that case.

I'm talking about my total debt at the end of a simulation. I run 100000 simulations, record debt at the end of each and take stdev of them. By the way, mean is equal to mean of payoff and to result of BSM.

What is this notation != ?  Are you asking why the Stdev is zero or why it isn’t zero ?

why it does not equal to zero

Seems like I got an answer. Delta hedging - is a first order of Tailor series. Neglect of other members creates error. Therefore hedge is not perfect.

That's because of gamma. The imperfect hedge resulting from gamma and other greeks (same level or higher order) generates imperfect hedges and residual pnl. I believe this is different from what you are describing is your issue here.

Disclaimer - I did not read your code.
According to what I understand, your stdev is the stdev across 100,000 values of total debt at the maturity of those 100,000 simulations (where the underlying stock price evolution is stochastic).
I don't believe there is any reason for the stdev to be zero.
The total debt is a result of borrowing capital to go long on stock to delta hedge (the short European call option) and is continuously readjusted at every single time period to make the total position delta-neutral. You can think of this way:
$$
Underlying \: Spot \rightarrow Delta \rightarrow Hedging \: Stock \: Position \rightarrow  Borrowed \: Capital
$$
where since the underlying spot is stochastic, the amount of borrowed capital would also follow a random path. Therefore, the total debt at the maturity of the option would definitely be different for each simulation, and the stdev would be non-zero.
